# How do I get to use variables from two different methods, in a new method?

Tags: java, eclipse, variables, methods

I have written a code which reads in two text files in seperate methods.

These are the files:

Accountnumbers and balances

```
0015      112.34
0020     4000.00
0034     9345.89
0069      723.50
0085     1500.00
0091     8237.31
0128       29.75
0129     -483.14
0135     2908.83
0189    10045.90
0251     5700.10
0396       29.75
0404     3299.99
0563     1000.02
2678    -5679.23
4561       12.00
8888        0.00
9999     9876.78
```

Accountnumbers, a deposit (1) or withdrawal (2), and the amount

```
0015   1   2000.00
2678   1   5000.00
0189   1    250.00
0034   2    500.00
0085   1    375.00
0404   2     72.49
0128   2     30.00
0189   1    250.00
4561   1     10.00
0020   2    189.70
0015   2   1000.00
0010   1    500.00
```

From these files I created different variables, also in two different methods. Now, I want to create a new method, in which I work with variables from the other two methods.

Here is my code with an extra class.

```
package Bank;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import ui.UIAuxiliaryMethods;

class Bank {

    PrintStream out;

     Bank() { 
            out = new PrintStream(System.out); 
            }

     void readAccountsIn() {
         Scanner fileScanner = UIAuxiliaryMethods.askUserForInput().getScanner();

         while(fileScanner.hasNext()) {
             String Account = fileScanner.nextLine();
             readAccountLine(Account);
         }
     }

     void readMutationsIn() {
         Scanner fileScanner1 = UIAuxiliaryMethods.askUserForInput().getScanner();
         while(fileScanner1.hasNext()) {
             String Mutation = fileScanner1.nextLine();
             readMutationLine(Mutation);
         }
     }


     void readAccountLine(String Account) {
         String[] parts = Account.split("\\s+");
         String account1 = parts[0];
         String balance1 = parts[1];
         double balance = Double.parseDouble(balance1);
             Accounts line = new Accounts(account1, balance);
             out.printf("%s %.2f \n",line.account1, line.balance);
         }

     void readMutationLine(String Mutation) {
         String[] parts = Mutation.split("\\s+");
         String account = parts[0];
         String type1 = parts[1];
         String mutation1 = parts[2];
         int type = Integer.parseInt(type1);
         double mutation = Double.parseDouble(mutation1);
         Mutations line1 = new Mutations(account, type, mutation);
         out.printf("%s %d %.2f \n",line1.account, line1.type, line1.mutation);
     }

     void start() {
         readAccountsIn();
         readMutationsIn();
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new Bank().start();
    }

}

package Bank;

class Accounts {

    String account1;
    double balance;

    Accounts(String account1, double balance){

        this.account1 = account1;
        this.balance = balance;
    }

}
```

I want to create a new method called Summary() in which I use all the variables (account1 and balance) from readAccountline() and (account, type, mutation) readMutationLine(). Is there any way to do this?

Comment: what do you mean? you can't access them from another method, as they're local to that method.

Answer (score 2):

First name your class `Account` and use `accountName` for your string, the model should reflect the real use

---

Your `Bank` should hve a list of `Account` to store and use them

```
class Bank {

    PrintStream out;
    List<Account> accounts;
    Bank() { 
        out = new PrintStream(System.out); 
        accounts = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Then when creating `Account` instanes, save them

```
void readAccountLine(String account) {
   //...
   Account acc = new Account(account1, balance);
   accounts.add(acc);
}
```

Then you could write the `toString` method that would summarize the Bank's content

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Bank");
    for (Account a : accounts)
        sb.append(a);         // you may write the toString() for Account too
    return sb.toString();
}
```

And use like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Bank b = new Bank();
    b.start();
    System.out.println(b); // will call toString();
}
```

Then do the same for `Mutations`

Comment: Is there some import needed for List<> ? Because it doesn't recognize it when I do it

Comment: @AtalAtmar yes import java.util.List, and java.util.ArrayList, you should use an IDE, it'll suggest you them or auto import them ;)

Comment: What I am actually trying to do is, to take every accountnumber and look for the mutations in the other file. I added the files in my question above. Then I want to get a summary which looks like this: 0015 112.34 2 1 1139.84. Which is the accountnumber, balance from the first file, the number of deposits, the number of withdrawals, and the amount of money left after deposits and withdrawals.

Comment: @AtalAtmar And so ? I won't do it for you, you seems to be too much far of getting all the key to solve this problem, you may learn more abour list manipulation, accessing the object in lists, ... ;)

Comment: I have done the above steps, seems to be working. But I get a summary like this when I run it: Bank.Account@38afe297, Bank.Account@2df3b89c, Bank.Account@23348b5d, Bank.Account@70325e14,... Is there a way to just create variables out of the arraylist and use them?

Comment: @AtalAtmar you just need to write the tostring method in Account class for the account to show well. For mutation : iterate over accounts, if ID matches, modify the account

Comment: @AtalAtmar I spend time to answer you well it'd be nice to reward it by accepting the answer ;)